# Kill -SIGSTOP and -SIGCONT in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, cron

I want to pause and continue a process at certain times, then I wrote this in crontab:

```
1 18 * * * kill -SIGSTOP xxxx
1 2 * * * kill -SIGCONT xxxx
```

It never works.

Every day I have to pause it manually before I leave work at 19:00, and when I check it at the next morning, various things happens.

Sometimes I find the process had disappeared.

Sometimes the process is still in paused state, and I can successfully continue it with -SIGCONT.

Sometimes when I manually send -SIGCONT, the paused process disaapears.

Comment: Is the computer always on? I suppose that the cron daemon is always running

Comment: I assume you are actually using the PID of the process you'd like to stop/continue in your kill command (where you have xxxx)

Comment: @sjsam Yes .It's a server that never shutdowns.

Comment: @J. Murray  The xxxx is the pid of the process. It works well when I manually execute the command.

Comment: Not all code written likes that system calls returns EINTR